# Django- Group by and Count by unique together

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-orm, django-aggregation

I have following models:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=30)

class PostView(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(Post, related_name='views', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), related_name='my_views')
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

I want to get post views count, grouped by hour of day and unique. 
 for example if a user sees a post at 10 AM 20 times, just one time should be calculated.
I get the posts in hours by views (not unique views) as following:

```
from django.db.models.functions import TruncHour
from django.db.models import Count

qs = PostView.objects.all().annotate(
        hour=TruncHour('created')
    ).values(
        'hour'
    ).annotate(
        c=Count('id')
    ).values('hour', 'c')
```

above code will calculate all views as total views. I want to get unique views by `user_id` and `hour` and `post_id` together.
Is it possible to do that with ORM?

Comment: I think you're looking for `distinct()` see: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet.distinct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this,

```
from django.db.models import Count

result = PostView.objects.values(
    "created__hour",
    "post",
    "user"
).annotate(count=Count("id"))

print(list(result))

# Result
# [{'created__hour': 17, 'post': 1, 'user': 1, 'count': 4}, {'created__hour': 17, 'post': 2, 'user': 1, 'count': 3}]
```

Comment: By using a `for` after `result` I calculated the unique views and my problem solved. But I'm wondering isn't any ways to calculate this unique views totally by ORM?

Answer (score 1):

Short Answer SQL & Django

```
select a.day_hour, count(*) from (select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', created) as day_hour, 
user_id, count(*)  from post_postview 
where post_id=1 group by strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', created), user_id) 
a group by a.day_hour
```

Django Answer

```
In [140]: rs = PostView.objects.filter(post_id=1).extra(
{'date_hour': u"strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H', created)"}).order_by('date_hour').values('user_id', 'date_hour').annotate(count=Count('user_id', distinct=True))

In [141]: rs
Out[141]: <QuerySet [{'date_hour': '2021-05-28 10', 
'user_id': 2, 'count': 1}, {'date_hour': '2021-05-28 10', 
'user_id': 3, 'count': 1}, {'date_hour': '2021-05-28 11', 
'user_id': 2, 'count': 1}, {'date_hour': '2021-05-28 11', 
'user_id': 3, 'count': 1}]>

In [142]: rs.values('date_hour').distinct()
Out[142]: <QuerySet [{'date_hour': '2021-05-28 10'}, 
{'date_hour': '2021-05-28 11'}]>
```

You need to group by twice. First time on `date_hour` and `user_id` and second time on the existing result set on `date_hour`.

Long Answer:

Since the query is on two levels(date level and unique user) you need two queries.

In the first step, you group the post created by `post_hour`. Without this fundamental aggregation result will show wrong values.

```
db.sqlite3> select strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', created) as 
day_hour, user_id, count(*)  from post_postview where 
post_id=1 group by strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H', created), user_id
+---------------+---------+----------+
| day_hour      | user_id | count(*) |
+---------------+---------+----------+
| 2021-05-28 10 | 2       | 1        |
| 2021-05-28 10 | 3       | 2        |
| 2021-05-28 11 | 2       | 3        |
| 2021-05-28 11 | 3       | 2        |
+---------------+---------+----------+
```

As you can see for the same time interval(2021-05-28 10),
there are `2` rows. Now to count this two rows, the extra query is required.

Again applying the same group by `day_hour`, we get the results per hour.

```
select a.day_hour, count(*) from (select strftime('%Y-%m-%d 
%H', created) as day_hour, user_id, count(*)  from 
post_postview where post_id=1 group by strftime('%Y-%m-%d 
%H', created), user_id) a group by a.day_hour;

+---------------+----------+
| day_hour      | count(*) |
+---------------+----------+
| 2021-05-28 10 | 2        |
| 2021-05-28 11 | 2        |
+---------------+----------+
```

Here I have used SQLite specific `strftime` which is important piece.

The same code is ported to Django as

```
In [145]: 
PostView.objects.filter(post_id=1).extra({'date_hour': 
u"strftime('%%Y-%%m-%%d %%H', 
created)"}).order_by('date_hour').values('user_id', 
'date_hour').values('date_hour').distinct()
Out[145]: <QuerySet [{'date_hour': '2021-05-28 10'}, 
{'date_hour': '2021-05-28 11'}]>
```

`extra` methods let's you inject SQL specific function and results afterwards follow general Django `order_by` and `distinct`. SQLite doesn't support distinct on.